# how to use R to generate equal number of samples over intervals of one variable

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, random

I would like to do the following:

1. There is a random variable X. It ranges from 0 to 1. We can let X follows an uniform distribution first for simplicity. But X can be skewed
2. I would like to divide X into 5 equal spaced intervals [0,0.2], [0.2,0.4],[0.4,0.6],[0.6,0.8],[0.8,1] and I would like to generate 100 random samples for X but with equal numbers over 5 intervals.

i.e., 20 X values from [0, 0.2], 20 values from [0.2, 0.4], and so on

I have been thinking about using counting. I will

1. create counter1, counter2, counter3, counter4, counter5 for each of 5 intervals.
2. generate a X random value, if it falls into one interval, I will add 1 to the counter for that interval
3. Once the counter is over 20, no more value from that interval will be accepted.

```r
x<-numeric(100)

cnt.1=0
cnt.2=0
cnt.3=0
cnt.4=0
cnt.5=0

### generate 100 samples ###
for (i in 1: 100) {

check=0

while(check==0){

rv<-runif(1)

    if(rv<=1 & rv>0.8){
      x[i]<-rv
      check<-ifelse(cnt.1>20,0,1)   
      cnt.1=cnt.1+1  
     } else {
      if(rv<=0.8 & rv>0.6){
      x[i]<-rv
      check<-ifelse(cnt.2>20,0,1)   
      cnt.2=cnt.2+1
      } else {
      if(rv<=0.6 & rv>0.4){
      x[i]<-rv
      check<-ifelse(cnt.3>20,0,1)   
      cnt.3=cnt.3+1
      } else{
      if(rv<=0.4 & rv>0.2){
      x[i]<-rv
      check<-ifelse(cnt.4>20,0,1)   
      cnt.4=cnt.4+1
      } else{
      x[i]<-rv
      check<-ifelse(cnt.5>20,0,1)   
      cnt.5=cnt.5+1
      } 
            }
 }
}
}
}

#check numbers from each interval
sim.cut<-cut(x,breaks=seq(0,1,by=0.2),include.lowest =TRUE)
```

It looks like I still can not get the exact same number of samples for each interval. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> matrix(runif(100,0,0.2),5)+seq(0,0.8, by = 0.2)
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]      [,7]
[1,] 0.1793394 0.04033639 0.01235725 0.1539683 0.1554890 0.05344413 0.0680698
[2,] 0.2531017 0.37967794 0.24119491 0.2995398 0.3869410 0.27722282 0.2964160
[3,] 0.4744248 0.58893505 0.43531135 0.5435237 0.4424285 0.40267807 0.5199132
[4,] 0.7145707 0.73215956 0.73740457 0.7983812 0.7303348 0.67647759 0.6987083
[5,] 0.9816416 0.92582281 0.87682074 0.8760070 0.8251110 0.97393817 0.8372435
          [,8]       [,9]     [,10]     [,11]      [,12]      [,13]     [,14]
[1,] 0.1654747 0.08225489 0.1059439 0.1385463 0.01413581 0.08136604 0.1301741
[2,] 0.3336933 0.36418926 0.3578712 0.2955239 0.21989323 0.38257518 0.2516034
[3,] 0.5588480 0.52941204 0.4046662 0.5722419 0.46325434 0.45872067 0.4957090
[4,] 0.6215887 0.75658655 0.6954460 0.6876194 0.70372685 0.69181315 0.7532621
[5,] 0.9447422 0.91060726 0.9464627 0.8489595 0.93240102 0.86647893 0.8168494
         [,15]      [,16]     [,17]     [,18]      [,19]     [,20]
[1,] 0.1750643 0.09527025 0.1921236 0.1514174 0.02866088 0.1557829
[2,] 0.2678146 0.37843967 0.2869319 0.2405385 0.24792588 0.3594618
[3,] 0.5678881 0.57286789 0.5425029 0.5422242 0.41178688 0.4910549
[4,] 0.6693367 0.67799791 0.6799989 0.6243384 0.72845765 0.6820168
[5,] 0.8667550 0.95546414 0.8650704 0.8490977 0.97525384 0.9621740
```

where each row has 20 samples, and from top to bottom (by rows) you have 5 intervals.